# Is there any way to arrange contents column-wise in tikzposter?

Tags: spacing, columns, posters, tikzposter

I want to divide my `tikzposter` in two columns and want to add contents column-wise, i.e., first add contents to first column and then to second but I can't find any way to do this. My major concern is the unused vertical space left between two column-pairs as shown in the attachment produced by the following code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Ttitle}
\date{01.03.2017}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Textbox 1}{
        \blinditemize[5]
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Textbox 2}{
        \blinditemize[10]
    }
\end{columns}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Textbox 3}{
        \blinditemize[5]
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Textbox 4}{
        \blinditemize[10]
    }
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use just one `columns` environment, and multiple `block`s in the same `column`.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Ttitle}
\date{01.03.2017}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Textbox 1}{
        \blinditemize[5]
    }
    \block{Textbox 3}{
        \blinditemize[5]
    }


    \column{0.5}
    \block{Textbox 2}{
        \blinditemize[10]
    }
    \block{Textbox 4}{
        \blinditemize[10]
    }
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]